# Passing in window to this in browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, browserify

One of my dependencies uses the following to pass in window to its closure

```
(function (window) {
   //
})(this)
```

For the time being I can just change it to something more sensible so that it doesn't break browserify, but is there some method whereby I can force a value for `this` in a browserified module?

Comment: Does `this` not correspond to the global object when browserify bundles the modules?

Comment: In this particular case no. I'm not sure why (or what the norm is). Here is the actual file if you want to have a go: https://abcjs.googlecode.com/files/abcjs_basic_1.8-min.js

Comment: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/372 - `this` doesn't refer to the global scope in general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [wrote a browserify transform called "moduleify"](https://www.npmjs.org/package/moduleify) that should generally do what you want, i.e. wrap the offending code in an IIFE that looks kinda like this:

```
(function () {
// this === window
}.call(window));
```

In fact, [my implementation](https://github.com/pluma/moduleify/blob/master/index.js) is not much more sophisticated than that.

The original idea was to export a globals-polluting "module" as if it were a CommonJS module (e.g. have AngularJS export `window.angular`), but because it contains that wrapper, it should do the trick.

For instructions, see the README. If the offending script doesn't actually have anything it could reasonably export, just have it export `window` (which will result in `module.exports = window['window']`) or an arbitrary name that doesn't exist (resulting in `undefined`).

If you want to access the `window` object in your own browserify code, also check out the [global](https://www.npmjs.org/package/global) module, which provides a nice wrapper to access browser globals safely in CommonJS modules.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this specific problem, a simple transform, that wraps the code in a self calling function, will do the job.

#### CoffeeScript

```
through = require('through')

fenestrate = (file) ->
  data = ';(function() {\n';

  write = (buf) ->
    data += buf

  end = ->
    data += '\n}).call(window);'
    this.queue(data)
    this.queue(null)
  through(write, end)
```

#### JavaScript

```
var through = require('through');

var fenestrate = function(file) {
  var data, end, write;
  data = ';(function() {\n';
  write = function(buf) {
    return data += buf;
  };
  end = function() {
    data += '\n}).call(window);';
    this.queue(data);
    return this.queue(null);
  };
  return through(write, end);
};
```

Writing Transforms: https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#transforms